# sync position of Unity camera to physical position of tango

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I'd like to have a my camera in the unity scene start where the Tango is positioned in a room. I have an ADF set up and it's loading correctly. The problem is the camera and pose controller are always starting at 0,0,0 in Unity.

If the tango is activated in the left side of the room I'd like the Pose in Unity to start at that left side of the scene, with respect to the ADF file.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the object positions to the position of tango using using a script on the camera and placing the logic in the Start() function.